# Unable to import module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why am I having an 'undefined bdir module' error, here is my directory,

a.py

bdir->bdir>module.py

in a.py

```
   from bdir import *
```

Comment: is a.py in the top level bdir?

Comment: a.py same level as first  bdir, second bdir got  /__init__.py,

Comment: which `bdir`? the first one or the one under it?

Answer (score 1):

Put an `__init__.py` file (even empty) in your bdir folder.

Answer (score 1):

Any folder without a `__init__.py` file inside of the folder is not considered a module. Furthermore, if you want to `import *` from a module, make sure that actually import the things you require into `__init__.py`, or declare a `__all__` list.

Also, if you want to make a *relative* import, meaning that you want to import a file from the package that a module is currently in, then you do a relative import. So, for example, if you have:

```
bdir
  - bdir
     - __init__.py
     - module.py
     - a.py
```

In order to import anything from the `bdir.module`, you have to import it like so if you are in `a.py`:

```
from .module import *
```

If outside the `bdir` module then:

```
from bdir.module import *
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create a `__init__.py` file, that's how Python knows which folders are packages that can be imported using the `import`. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search
>   path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but
>   it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the
>   `__all__` variable.